# Getting Error while inserting Stored Procedure result in temp

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have multiple select statements in Stored Procedure and I wants to insert result of select statement into temp table.
I have already created temp table. I am using mysql workbench. Here is my some code

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `PNL1`()
BEGIN    

SELECT sum(amount), groupname FROM ( (SELECT -(ramount) AS amount, rgroupname AS groupname FROM receiptsvoucher2) UNION ALL (SELECT -(ramount2) AS amount, rgroupname2 AS groupname FROM receiptsvoucher2) UNION ALL (SELECT pyamount AS amount,pygroupname AS groupname FROM paymentvoucher2) UNION ALL (SELECT pyamount2 AS amount, pygroupname2 AS groupname FROM paymentvoucher2) UNION ALL (SELECT jamount1 AS amount, jgroupname AS groupname FROM journalvoucher2) UNION ALL (SELECT -(jamount2) AS amount,jgroupname2 AS groupname FROM journalvoucher2) ) p where groupname='Other Expenses';

insert into temp(amount1,groupname1) values(amount, groupname);

execute PNL1;

select * from temp;

END
```

I am getting this error

Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'amount' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This,

```
insert into temp(amount1,groupname1) 
SELECT sum(amount), groupname FROM ( 
(SELECT -(ramount) AS amount, rgroupname AS groupname FROM receiptsvoucher2) 
 UNION ALL 
(SELECT -(ramount2) AS amount, rgroupname2 AS groupname FROM receiptsvoucher2) 
 UNION ALL 
(SELECT pyamount AS amount,pygroupname AS groupname FROM paymentvoucher2) 
 UNION ALL
(SELECT pyamount2 AS amount, pygroupname2 AS groupname FROM paymentvoucher2)
 UNION ALL 
(SELECT jamount1 AS amount, jgroupname AS groupname FROM journalvoucher2) 
 UNION ALL 
(SELECT -(jamount2) AS amount,jgroupname2 AS groupname FROM journalvoucher2) ) p  
where groupname='Other Expenses';
```

More on [Insert-Select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)